# Simple Drag and Drop into Window returning file path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.3

I want to implement simple drag and drop in my application.
If you drag a file into window I want to return
the file-path with NSLog. Here is my code but 
nothing happens if I drag a file. By the way I
connected AppDelegate with referencing outlets
with window (delegate) to receive everything from window.

AppDelegate.m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
      [_window registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]]; 
}

-(NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    return NSDragOperationGeneric;
}
-(BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    NSPasteboard* pbrd = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSArray *draggedFilePaths = [pbrd propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    // Do something here.
    return YES;

   NSLog(@"string2 is %@",draggedFilePaths);}

@end
```

---

AppDelegate.h:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  testdrag
//
//  Created by admin on 18.07.12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>


@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 2):

Only objects which occupy screen space -- windows or views -- can accept and handle dragging events. Your app delegate is neither of those. Further, the window does not send *any* message it receives to its delegate. It only sends messages that are part of the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol. You need to implement this dragging code in a view class, an instance of which appears on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but here is how I solved this problem:

I made a subclass of `NSWindow`, named it `MainWindow`. Then I added the protocol `NSDraggingDestination` to the new class `MainWindow`. In the Interface Builder, I selected the application window, and put `MainWindow` as classname in the Identity Inspector.

In the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [_window registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
}
```

And the implementation of `MainWindow`:

```
#import "MainWindow.h"

@implementation MainWindow

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    printf("Awake\n");
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    printf("Enter\n");
    return NSDragOperationEvery;
}

/*
- (NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    return NSDragOperationEvery;
}
*/

- (void)draggingExited:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    printf("Exit\n");
}

- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    printf("Prepare\n");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    printf("Perform\n");

    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType] ) {
        NSArray *files = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        unsigned long numberOfFiles = [files count];
        printf("%lu\n", numberOfFiles);
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    printf("Conclude\n");
}

@end
```

Works like a charm! (Finally!)